# Google+ sign in button cannot be cancel

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am new to Android development and hope to get some advice for the problem I am facing.

My app requires me to implement a google+ sign in button.

**My progress**

- I followed the guidelines and completed all necessary setup steps for a google+ sign in button
- I am able to use sign in button and retrieve profile email

**My problem**

- When the google+ sign in button is clicked, the "select account" dialog shows, which allows a user to select from multiple possible gmail accounts
- When user click an account and then click confirm button, everything works fine
- **But**, when user click the cancel button in the dialog, the dialog disappears and reappears. Even if you click the back button, the dialog disappears and reappears.

This prevents the user from choosing other login options.

I am wondering what is wrong with my code, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // facebook sign in
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    facebookLoginSetup(findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView());

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();

    SignInButton sign_in_button = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    setGooglePlusButtonText(sign_in_button, getString(R.string.google_login_button_label));

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.global_message_loading));
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    // google
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();
        }
    } else {
        // facebook
        // call registered call back method
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause)
{
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        if(!mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        mSignInClicked = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    if(mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
        String userEmail = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        createUser(userEmail);
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "onConnectionFailed keep retrying");
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            startIntentSenderForResult(result.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
            // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
            mIntentInProgress = false;
        }
    }
}


    // google custom button
protected void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setTextSize(15);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
            tv.setText(buttonText);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the whole content of the onConnectionFailed? It may be that canceling the login is counted as a connection failure and currently the response from your app to it is to try again.

Answer (score 0):

In **onActivityResult** method check resultCode.

```
if(responseCode == RESULT_OK){

//User clicked sign in do your stuff

}else if(responseCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

//User clicked cancel

 mIntentInProgress = true;

}

   //if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
```

Now **onConnectionFailed** wont execute **startIntentSenderForResult**

Answer (score 0):

I have also this same issue, solved with this

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, "cancel");
                    editor.apply();
                    this.finish();
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For a "cancel" action, (responseCode != RESULT_OK) returns true as well so I catch it in the onActivityResult(..) method . Here is the code:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
        }else if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();                   
            }           
        }
        mIntentInProgress = false;
    } else {
        ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode,   data);
    }

}
```